# "AttributeError: 'module' has no attribute 'player'" when attempting to load python object into C++ with Boost::Python

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

Error in terminal as follows:

```
AttributeError: 'module' has no attribute 'player'
```

Python file: character_py.py

```
import sys
sys.path.append('./character')
import character

player = character.Character('!',0,0)
```

And the C++ file: Character.cpp

```
#include "../inc/Character.hpp"
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

using namespace boost::python;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(character)
{
  class_<Character>("Character", init<char, int, int>())
    .def("Position", &Character::Position)
    .def("GetRow", &Character::GetRow)
    .def("GetCol", &Character::GetCol)
    .def("GetSymbol", &Character::GetSymbol)
    .def("SetRow", &Character::SetRow)
    .def("SetCol", &Character::SetCol)
    .def("SetSymbol", &Character::SetSymbol)
    ;
}

Character::Character(char s, int r, int c) 
{
  symbol = s;
  row = r;
  col = c;

  Initialize();
}

void Character::Initialize()
{
  object character_m = import("character_py");
  object player = character_m.attr("player");
}
```

I've been working on this problem for a few days now, and I can't seem to figure out the loading of the actual object from the python module I've created. I can import it just fine. I can execute python code from C++. But I can't get this data out of the script. I have tried using a dictionary with:

```
object character_dict = character_m.attr("__dict__");
object player = character_dict["player"];
```

But I get the same error every time.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I am essentially at a dead stop until I can solve this particular problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code has no way to work. You are trying to get an instance of the object in the middle of creating it.

To put that into the picture in C++ (code results in infinite recursion):

```
struct Character;

Character get_character();

struct Character
{
    Character()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    void Initialize()
    {
        Character c = get_character();
    }
};

Character get_character() { return Character(); }

int main()
{
    Character c;

    return 0;
}
```

To make your code work you have to execute python code somewhere else than in `Character` constructor / functions called in `Character` constructor.

Comment: Oh my god, it is so obvious and so simple. Thank you. Sometimes you think you are a really experienced programmer, and then you write something like this. Seriously though, this was a huge help.